# Variable initialization in the variable_scope in the Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I've been trying to understand how variables are initialized in Tensorflow. Below, I created a simple example which defines a variable in some `variable_scope` and the process is wrapped in the subfunction.

In my understanding, this code creates a variable `'x'` inside the `'test_scope'` at  `tf.initialize_all_variables()` stage and it can always be accessed after that using `tf.get_variable()`. But this code ended up with the `Attempting to use uninitialized value` error at `print(x.eval())` line.

I don't have any idea about how Tensorflow initializes variables. Can I get any help? Thank you.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def create_var_and_prod_with(y):
    with tf.variable_scope('test_scope'):
        x = tf.Variable(0.0, name='x', trainable=False)
    return x * y

s = tf.InteractiveSession()
y = tf.Variable(1.0, name='x', trainable=False)
create_var_and_prod_with(y)

s.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

with tf.variable_scope('test_scope'):
    x = tf.get_variable('x', [1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), trainable=False)
    print(x.eval())
    print(y.eval())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse a variable, you have to declare it using `get_variables` and than explicitly ask to the scope to make the variables reusable.

If you change the line

```
 x = tf.Variable(0.0, name='x', trainable=False)
```

with:

```
x = tf.get_variable('x', [1], trainable=False)
```

And you ask to the scope to make the already defined variable available:

```
with tf.variable_scope('test_scope') as scope:
     scope.reuse_variables()
      x = tf.get_variable('x', [1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), trainable=False)
```

Then you can run `print(x.eval(), y.eval())` without problems.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did it along with your suggestion and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse a variable with `tf.get_variable('x')`, the variable has to be created in the first place with `tf.get_variable('x').

Moreover, when you want to retrieve a created variable, you need to be in a scope with`reuse=True`.

---

Here is what your code should look like:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def create_var_and_prod_with(y):
    with tf.variable_scope('test_scope'):
        x = tf.get_variable('x', [1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), trainable=False)
    return x * y

y = tf.Variable(1.0, name='x', trainable=False)
create_var_and_prod_with(y)

with tf.variable_scope('test_scope', reuse=True):
    x = tf.get_variable('x')  # you only need the name to retrieve x

# Try to put the session only at the end when it is needed
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print(x.eval())
    print(y.eval())
```

---

You can read more about it in [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you told, get_variable() arguments were redundant at the retrieval step. reuse=True option seems equivalent to scope.reuse_variables() function call. It also worked. Thanks.